# Remove redundant pending status checks in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline where a bunch of statuses for various stages are set to pending in our github at the start of the pipeline.

During the course of the pipeline, some of these stages may get skipped due to some conditionals

example of my stages:

```
stage('Build') {
    when {
        allOf {
            branch "PR-*"
            expression { some expression... }
        }
    }
    steps {
        echo "GATE 2 - Build"
        sh "some commands..."
    }
    post {
        success {
            script {
                setStatus('build', 'success')
            }
        }
        failure {
            script {
                setStatus('build', 'failure')
            }
        }
    }
}

stage('Test') {
    when {
        allOf {
            branch "PR-*"
            expression { some expression... }
        }
    }
    steps {
        echo "GATE 2 - Test"
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            sh "some commands..."
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            setStatus('test', 'success')
        }
        failure {
            setStatus('test', 'failure')
        }
    }
}
```

setStatus

```
def call(String sectionName, String passOrFail) {
    pullRequest.createStatus(
            status: passOrFail,
            context: 'continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge/' + sectionName,
            description: sectionName + ' ' + passOrFail,
            targetUrl: "${env.BUILD_URL}"
    )

}
```

However, when stages do get skipped, this then ends up leaving the status checks in Github against pull requests as pending when the pipeline completes.

So my question is, is there a way to remove status checks magically, or maybe a way to detect which stages got skipped and do something with the status checks?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`not` condition](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions) with the same condition and expressions:

```groovy
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            parallel {
                stage('Build done') {
                    when {
                        expression {
                            buildConditions()
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo "GATE 2 - Build"
                        sh "echo 'Build commands...'"
                    }
                    post {
                        success {
                            script {
                                setStatus('build', 'success')
                            }
                        }
                        failure {
                            script {
                                setStatus('build', 'failure')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Build skipped') {
                    when {
                        not {
                            expression {
                                buildConditions()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        script {
                            setStatus('build', 'skipped')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /*
        stage('Test') {
            parallel {
                stage('Test done') {
                    // ... as above ...
                }
                stage('Test skipped') {
                    // ... as above ...
                }
            }
        }
        */
    }
}

def buildConditions() {
    return allOf {
        expression { true }
        expression { true }
    }    
}

def testConditions() {
    return allOf {
        expression { true }
        expression { true }
    }    
}
```

See also [Conditionals in a Declarative Pipeline Jenkinsfile](https://michakutz.medium.com/conditionals-in-a-declarative-pipeline-jenkinsfile-d1a4a44e93bb).